# Is there a way to filter based on text like?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In SQL, you are able to filter based on text using `LIKE "xxx%"`. I am essentially trying to do the same thing in R.

Two text lines contain symbols due to the way data was extracted so R does not recognize the exact line of text.

Essentially I am trying to get the following code to work but *"Enjoy the"* is not the complete text due to the symbols.

```
Premium <- emaild %>% 
  filter(Cell_Subject_Line == "Enjoy the")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods you can use. The `data.table` package has a `like` function, which can work in filtering much like SQL:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
Premium <- emaild %>% 
  filter(Cell_subject_line %like% "Enjoy the")
```

Otherwise you can use `stringr` functions like `str_detect()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
Premium <- emaild %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Cell_subject_line, pattern = "Enjoy the"))
```